# Upload files from android app to my S3 bucket

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm pretty confused about what method should I use. OK here's what I'm actually trying to do:

1. User registers with my app need to upload multiple files/images
2. These files/images need to be uploaded to **my** s3 bucket

Uploading these files using presigned URL seems to be out of the question since I need to upload multiple files/images and it seems presigned URL is only good for a single file.[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html)

I then look at AWS SDK for Java 2.0, and this seems what I need; however, when I read the `[setup credentials][1]` I become confused because:

1. It seems this will use the credentials setup in our OS environment. So how will my app use these credentials later when it's installed in other users' devices?
2. I have multiple AWS credentials profile in my OS. I'm still unclear on how to actually load my credentials profile, as it's not the default profile

So upon further reading the link, it seems supply credentials explicitly with

```
AwsSessionCredentials awsCreds = AwsSessionCredentials.create(
    "your_access_key_id_here",
    "your_secret_key_id_here",
    "your_session_token_here");
```

should fit me the best. But if I put my `access_key_id`, `secret_key_id` in my app's `strings.xml` file, wouldn't it be a security issue?

[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html) FYI I have successfully implemented upload single image using presigned URL for another activity. I use retrofit which connects to my lambda function which then returns the presigned URL, and made another retrofit PUT request to the presigned URL

Comment: Does your Android app authenticate to a server-side application that you control?

Comment: Why not get different presigned url for each of the files and upload one at a time?
Or you can zip the files together and upload the zipped file.
Or you can give the app temporary credentials with AWS cognito and upload with those credentials?

Comment: @jarmod yes, my app authenticate to a serverless (lambda) function. Since it's a lambda function, I don't/shouldn't upload any file there.

Comment: @ShahadIshraq I considered that possibility (different presigned url for each files) but due to several design choices, that's not the best method in my case. Zipping files are also a no-go since I need to use/access the uploaded files after a successful upload. Even if these 2 options can be considered, I still want to know how to actually solve the problem as described in my question.

Comment: Then I'd say authenticate the user with Cognito, get temporary credentials and upload the files with those credentials.

Comment: @ShahadIshraq I must admit I've never really heard about AWS Cognito before this. I just googled and it seems like an interesting solution, but it may be overkill for my use case, since I may need it to only upload the images to my S3. So there's no way I can achieve what I need without using Cognito?

Comment: Unfortunately as per my understanding, you can put only one object with one presigned url.

Comment: @ShahadIshraq yes I'm aware of that. What I meant was, is there no way to do what I wanted just by using AWS SDK?

Comment: Cognito and pre-signed URL options aside, your server can also simply call STS AssumeRole to get temporary AWS credentials and send those to the app client so that the client can use them with the AWS Android SDK to upload directly to S3. Ideally, the STS credentials that your server returns to the client are very time-limited and are very scoped down to just those permissions that are needed for the use case and the logged-in user (e.g. s3:PutObject to a very specific S3 bucket and prefix).

Comment: @jarmod thanks a lot. I just read more about STS and I think it will suit my need

Comment: @jarmod now I have a problem getting STS using AWS Java 2 SDK. If you don't mind, can point me to where I can get a working sample code to get STS using AWS Java 2 SDK?

Comment: See STS [assumeRole](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0-preview-11/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sts/StsClient.html#assumeRole-software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleRequest-) for reference and [here](https://joelforjava.com/blog/2019/11/27/using-assume-role-with-aws-sdk.html) for an example.